# MSSQL папка Log

Tags: sql-server

Всем привет.
Каталог C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log.
Занимает 9 гигов.
Можно ли из него, через проводник просто удалить все файлики?
В основном там txt файлы.

Answer (score 6):

Нельзя удалять файл ERRORLOG без расширения, если сервис сервера запущен, и можно, если остановлен. Файлы с числовыми расширениями (обычно от 1 до 6) можно удалять в любой момент без ограничения.

Но разумнее просто несколько раз запустить sp_cycle_errorlog - каждый его запуск вызывает закрытие текущего журнала, удаление самого старого, переименования существующих по цепочке и создание нового пустого журнала. Преимущество в том, что это ШТАТНОЕ действие, в отличие от удаления вручную.

Comment: А его вообще дадут удалить при запущенном сервисе?

Comment: Не знаю. Вот даже в голову не приходило пробовать...

Comment: Только что попробовал. Не удаляется.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Рекомендую создать План обслуживания (Maintenance Plan),в который включить таск чистки старых лог-файлов. Иначе продолжите сталкиваться с этой же проблемой в последствии.

[image: Пример таска]

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Сделал.